# Why is my query not working like expected?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, notin

I have a query where I am trying to get specific values where they are not in this other table but when I run the query I am getting no results. Here is what I am seeing. Please let me know what is going wrong.

Original query: Returns 399 Rows

```
        USE TFW_DEV

    SELECT
       unitid, unitnumber
     FROM
       Units
     WHERE 
        createdon BETWEEN '2016-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-11-03 23:59:59'
    ORDER BY
        unitnumber
```

Query to see where tables share data: Returns 50 Rows

```
USE TFW_DEV

SELECT
   unitid, unitnumber
 FROM
   Units
 WHERE 
    createdon BETWEEN '2016-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-11-03 23:59:59'
    AND unitid  IN
    (
        SELECT
            unitid
        FROM
            meteraudit      
    )
ORDER BY
    unitnumber
```

Final query with the NOT IN: Returns 0 rows

```
USE TFW_DEV

SELECT
   unitid, unitnumber
 FROM
   Units
 WHERE 
    createdon BETWEEN '2016-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-11-03 23:59:59'
    AND unitid NOT IN
    (
        SELECT
            unitid
        FROM
            meteraudit      
    )
ORDER BY
    unitnumber
```

I would expect the final query to return 349 rows correct? If not what am I doing wrong? Thank you,

Comment: Are there any  `NULL`  values for `unitid` in `meteraudit`?

Comment: There are a few rows where it is null.

Comment: That's the problem then. For both queries, you need to use `IN /* or NOT IN */ (SELECT unitid FROM meteraudit WHERE unitid IS NOT NULL)`

Comment: Yep that did it. Thank you. Throw your comment into an answer so I can mark it for you. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NOT IN` fails when there is a `NULL` value returned from the `Sub-Query`

Use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT unitid, 
       unitnumber 
FROM   units U 
WHERE  createdon BETWEEN '2016-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-11-03 23:59:59' 
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                       FROM   meteraudit M 
                       WHERE  U.unitid = M.unitid) 
ORDER  BY unitnumber
```